# HTML5 Canvas in Magento

Tags: html, magento

I am new to magento i want to know .In my project i want some customized product view in product view page.  But i am not getting any idea on this .Please let me know the possibility for using HTML5 canvas in magento 1.6.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you can edit the template file `catalog/product/view/media.phtml` which is where the product image is.

Comment: Hello Max, thanks for your response. I'll go through the media.phtml file.